# get GPS soon as possible

Tags: android

At the moment I'am working on project to messure frequency with gps :-). I like to get the gps information as soon as possible from GPS/Wifi. I also want to get it in the most highest frequency as possible. My goal is to messure a frequency from this data. At the moment I try it this way

```
final public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        while(gps){

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);




            try {
                Thread.sleep(100) ;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);

        }
        Looper.loop();
    }//run
```

Is there a better way to get a faster "samplerate"?

Answer (score 0):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html:

> You can control the frequency at which your listener receives updates with the second and third parameter—the second is the minimum time interval between notifications and the third is the minimum change in distance between notifications—**setting both to zero requests location notifications as frequently as possible**.

`requestLocationUpdates` gives you what you want. Not sure what you're trying to do with the while loop.

Comment: Sorry for my english...   Yes, I use this(requestLocationUpdates) but I try to find out to get faster new Information. When I request the LUpdates I get very fast (with Wifi) the location 900ms the next comes after 45000ms. So my idea was to turn it on and off to get "every 900ms" a new  Information. But I doesn't get it work in this thread.  I know it sound strange but my goal is to create a function with this information and plot it...  @Martin sorry no App for your blacklist @trutheality I use onLocationChanged() and I send Information to Gui/Mainthread...   hope I make myself more clearly

Comment: You can try and see if `requestSingleUpdate` gives you more frequent updates, as it would be more appropriate to use it in a loop.

Comment: Also, what is happening is your loop does not wait for the update to be received because location updates happen asynchronously (what you're doing right now is the equivalent of opening and closing a door every 100ms without anyone walking through, while you're waiting for someone to walk through.)

Comment: Is the first update always 900ms? I suspect that the actual sampling rate is 1 per 45000ms and the first one is always going to come in less than 45000ms after you set up the listener, but that's because you set up the listener between two sampling times, not because it's faster on the first one.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply! Yes the first time it comes very fast(like 900ms - 1500 ms)(using Wifi!!). And yes you are right the range of new following values lon/lat is between 5- 45 seconds.. . Damm, requestsingleUpdate come with 2.3.1 and my phone use 2.2 Api. You think it is worth to update my phone?(I "hate" this rooting stuff :-) ) Thank You again!!

Comment: I don't think that you'll get a big difference with `requestSingleUpdate`, it was just an idea. The other idea is to wait for a location update before you do `removeUpdates` instead of just `sleep(100)`.

Comment: I try it this way:but I get no new event...  final public void run() {


        Looper.prepare();

        while(gps){
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mLocationListener);


        while(!getnewGPS){
            //tic tac
        }
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
        getnewGPS = false;

        Looper.loop();
        }
    }//run

Answer (score 0):

Get lat long using GPS in every 10 min.

```
//  Des: Start Device's GPS and get current latitude and longitude
    public void GPS() throws IOException {

//  Des: This is a background service and called after every 10 minutes and fetch                    latitude-longitude values
     background = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {             
            for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
                if (ProjectStaticVariable.GPSExit == true ) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(600000);   //10 minutes
                    mainhandler.sendMessage(mainhandler.obtainMessage());
                    j++;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                 }
               }
            }
         }
    });

    background.start();
    mainhandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

   //   Check Internet status
            isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
            if (isInternetPresent) {

                lat_long_Service_flag = true;                   
                mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(getApplicationContext());
                mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0,  mlocListener);

                mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            }
        }
    };
}

  //   Des: Location Listener through which we get current latitude and longitude
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public MyLocationListener(Context mContext) {}

    public MyLocationListener(Runnable runnable) {}

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {

        longitude = loc.getLongitude();
        latitude = loc.getLatitude();
        final_latitude = Double.toString(latitude);
        final_longitude = Double.toString(longitude);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```